# Working in Switzerland with French residence permit

Tags: working-visas, job-hunting, working

Is it possible to work in Switzerland with a French residence permit?

Comment: No, it's not possible (that's actually too short for an answer but that's all there is to say).

Comment: @Gala care to update with an official source for an answer?